# Execute different statements in one query on the condition

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

Say we have two Users with `ID = 1` and `ID = 2`

I know the `ID` of the current User and I need to execute different `select` statements depending on the `ID`.

```
if ID = 1
select a from table1
else if ID = 2
select b from table2
else
select c from table3
```

Is there a way to put this logic into single **SQL** query?

Comment: ID is column in table1, table2, table3 or variable and have any of these table column with name ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union` with appropriate `where` conditions.

```
select a from table1 where id = 1
union all
select b from table2 where id = 2
union all
select c from table3 where id not in (1,2)
```

or if the tables can be `join`ed

```
select 
case when t1.id = 1 then t1.a
     when t2.id = 2 then t2.b
else t3.c end
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

Comment: In my understanding this approach leads to redundant computations if only exactly one condition is met each time.

Comment: @Sloth This calculation takes miliseconds. CBO is smart enough not to fetch data if condition is always false(means 1=2 if id = 2)

Comment: @EvgeniyK. Imagine if evaluation of the condition is expensive enough.
My example is very simplified

Comment: post what you are trying to do then

Comment: Look, for my user I need to get a list of his roles and check if this list intersects with some another list of roles. I want to not evaluate next conditions if previous has been met.

Comment: include an explanation with sample data on what *exactly* you are trying to accomplish. What you have so far is vague.

Comment: `where id = 1` replace this with `some complex statement` and that's all

Comment: I think It'll be okay to perform precalculation in `with` block. And then use precalculated info in where statements.